# Unable to format my USB Flash Drive after installing a Distro to the drive itself

Tags: kali-linux, usb-drive, corruption

This may sound stupid, and it is, I installed a distro directly into my flash drive, after checking everything worked I loaded kali liveUSB to try and format it back to it's original size, however none of my attempts seems to be working, below is a list of what I've tried so far:

- Using gParted

[image: Here whats showing on Gparted]

[image: Selecting disks to format]

As of now trying to format using gParted I get the following error messages
[image: Error message #1]
[image: Error message #2]
[image: Error message #3]
And This shows at the ending of the operation
[image: Shows at the ending]

After that, running fdisk -l shows no external flash drives, then after removing and re-inserting it shows.

- Using Data Description (dd)

I already tried using Data Description but get the following error message
[image: fdisk -l and dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1024]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Input/output error might be a hardware problem. Probably unrelated to the specific problem: Are you aware that Kali is a special purpose distribution for experts, not for general use? (https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/330217)

Comment: First create a partition, then format the drive.

Comment: As of trying to partition the device it won't let me, and the flash drive will only disconnect, only appearing again after re-inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows system you can use diskpart "clean" command and then create and format a new partition which will give you a new exfat or fat32 formatted thumb drive which both Linux and Windows will recognize and mount.

Try this tutotrial as well:

https://averagelinuxuser.com/how-to-format-bootable-usb-to-normal/

Comment: You might want to fix the typo of "tutotrial" (to [tutorial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tutorial)). I tried doing it myself, but was not allowed as the edit would be less than six characters.

Comment: Thank you for replying, however I tried it and it didn't work. The same problem occurs in windows, maybe I just lost this flash drive for ever